# Reference a dynamic block from within a module

Tags: terraform

I'm not 100% sure how to reference this dynamic block nested within the nsg root module.

I'm still quite new to Terraform and can't seem to figure this out, what am I missing here?

Is someone able to assist me with my code please.

Errors:

```
Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on nsgs.tf line 1, in module "nsg-subnet1-ansible":
│    1: module "nsg-subnet1-ansible" {
│
│ The argument "network_security_group_rules" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on nsgs.tf line 7, in module "nsg-subnet1-ansible":
│    7:   security_rule = [
│
│ An argument named "security_rule" is not expected here.
```

**NSG Modules Block**

```
module "nsg-subnet1-ansible" {
  network_security_group_name     = var.network_security_group_name
  network_security_group_location = module.rg-networkcore.location
  resource_group_name             = module.rg-networkcore.resource_group_name

  security_rule = [
    {

      name                       = "AllowSSH"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "22"
      source_address_prefix      = "?.?.?.?"
      destination_address_prefix = "*"

    }
  ]
}
```

**modules/nsg/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = var.network_security_group_name
  location            = var.network_security_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.network_security_group_rules
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value["name"]
      priority                   = security_rule.value["priority"]
      direction                  = security_rule.value["direction"]
      access                     = security_rule.value["access"]
      protocol                   = security_rule.value["protocol"]
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value["source_port_range"]
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value["source_address_prefix"]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
    }
  }
}
```

**modules/nsg/outputs.tf**

```
output "network_security_group_id" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.*.id
}

output "network_security_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name
}
```

**modules/nsg/variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of resource group"
}

variable "network_security_group_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
}

variable "network_security_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of nsg group"
}

# NSG Rule Variables
variable "network_security_group_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    priority                   = number
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  description = "The values for each NSG rule "
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dynamic` block you are using is called `"security_rule"`. However, in order to create a block of that type, you have set the `for_each` to loop over a variable called `network_security_group_rules`. That means that when you are calling the module, you should pass the `network_security_group_rules` to it, and not `security_rule`. Think of modules as of functions in other programming languages: you have a set of input variables you pass to your function. A similar thing applies here. Since your module has variables that do not provide any default values, that means you have to provide all of those when calling the module. Something of a pseudocode when calling a module would be:

```
module "nsg-subnet1-ansible" (resource_group_name, network_security_group_location, network_security_group_name, network_security_group_rules)
```

In other words, you would have to adjust the module call to look like this:

```
module "nsg-subnet1-ansible" {
  network_security_group_name     = var.network_security_group_name
  network_security_group_location = module.rg-networkcore.location
  resource_group_name             = module.rg-networkcore.resource_group_name

  network_security_group_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AllowSSH"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "22"
      source_address_prefix      = "?.?.?.?"
      destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I would strongly suggest using another variable in the root module, instead of hard-coding one rule. You could for example define a variable called `network_security_group_rules` in the root module and that would probably help you avoid confusion when calling the module in the future:

```
variable "network_security_group_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    priority                   = number
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  description = "Security Group rules settings."
}
```

The value of that variable would be:

```
network_security_group_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AllowSSH"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "22"
      source_address_prefix      = "?.?.?.?"
      destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
  ]
```

Then, in the module call, you would just use:

```
module "nsg-subnet1-ansible" {
  network_security_group_name     = var.network_security_group_name
  network_security_group_location = module.rg-networkcore.location
  resource_group_name             = module.rg-networkcore.resource_group_name

  network_security_group_rules = var.network_security_group_rules
}
```

That way if you decide to add new rules later you just add them to the variable value instead of adding it directly. There is a bit of repeating the code, but until you feel comfortable enough, this should help. Make sure you understand how to use `Input variables` in modules [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop#module-structure

Comment: Always happy to help!